# How to convert a physical path into virtual path in c#

Tags: c#

I want to stores the files in D drive

```
 string fileName = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath(@"D:\Files"), File_Video.FileName);
```

How can I convert it into virtual path

Comment: Can't you just save the files to a physical path straight away? You don't to map anything if you already know that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what your code sample is showing. `Server.MapPath` takes a virtual path as its parameter, not a physical path. If you want `filename` to contain a physical path then you just need to do:

```
string fileName = Path.Combine(@"D:\Files", File_Video.FileName);
```

If you want to know how to get the virtual directory for d:\files (eg so you can link to things in there) then this is harder since there is not necessarily any mapping. Usually to access these files you would either set up a virtual directory pointing at that physical path and have that hardcoded into your links. Otherwise you could create a proxy page that acts as aproxy to the files. This has the advantage of being able to do security checks and such like to make sure they are only accessible to logged on users, etc. (since video is big and you probably don't want the whole internet beign able to access it if they know the right url).

I hope this solves your problem. If not can you clarify more what your problem is?

Answer (score 0):

Server.MapPath() is basiclly used when you have a virtual Path. For Physical Path, you can directly use `Path.Combine(param1,param2)`

Hope this will help you!

Comment: What did your answer add that was not already explained by Chris?